# TypeError: Expected existing data to be a number, received string

Tags: javascript, database

I have been receiving this error when trying to exicute the command `.addmoney` and I'm not sure what to do

```
const { db } = require("../../main");

module.exports = {
        name: "addmoney",
        category: "economy",
        description: "Adds Money to a user",
        usage: ".addmoney [user] <amount>",
        accessableby: "Administrator, Owner",
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR", "MANAGE_GUILD")) return message.channel.send("You Do Not Have Permissions To Add Money... - [ADMINISTRATOR, MANAGE_GUILD]");
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("You forgot to mention a person")

        let user = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.find(r => r.user.username.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLocaleLowerCase()) || message.guild.members.cache.find(r => r.displayName.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLocaleLowerCase());
        if (!user) return message.channel.send("Enter A Valid User")
        if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send("I can not add an empty amount...")
        if (isNaN(args[1])) return message.channel.send(`Who taught you numbers? I really want to talk with that person`);
        if (args[0] > 10000) return message.channel.send("Have you even checked your balance yet? You are broke... Get a job first")
        const bal = await db.add(`money_${user.id}`, args[1])

        let moneyEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#00cbff')
            .setDescription(`Added ${args[1]} coins\n\nNew Balance: ${bal}`);
        message.channel.send(moneyEmbed)

    }
}
```

Comment: I would check the SQL itself.  Does the money column amount have quotes around it?  If yes, try removing the quotes.

Comment: Which money column do you mean?